# Left join query and 'ret' is not a recognized built-in function name error

Tags: c#, sql

I have Query for FillGrid

```
return DalCommon.OpenSql(@"SELECT ret.*, sli.sliContractNumberInt, sli.sliVCodeBig, con.conNameStr 
                                    FROM SLA.Return ret(nolock)
                                    left join SAL.SalesInvoice sli(nolock) on con.conVCodeInt=sli.sliconVCodeInt
                                    left join APP.APP_TBL_Contacts con(nolock) on con.conVCodeInt=sli.sliconVCodeInt
                              
                              Where(@retVCodeBig=0 OR retVCodeBig=@retVCodeBig)
                                    AND (ISNULL(@ContractNumberInt,''='' OR sli.sliContractNumberInt=@ContractNumberInt)
                                    AND (ISNULL(@VCodeBig,''='' OR sli.sliVCodeBig=@VCodeBig
                                    And (ISNULL(@txtConVCodeIntStr,'')='' OR  con.conNameStr like '%'+ @txtConVCodeIntStr +'%') 
                                    AND (ISNULL(@fromDate,'')='' OR  retDateStr>=@fromDate)
                                    AND (ISNULL(@toDate,'')='' OR retDateStr<=@toDate)", p);
```

and this is my error

- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Return'.
  'ret' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Your query has lots of problems if you are really using MySQL.  Please tag the question appropriately.  In addition, the SQL code has no `Return`, so this would appear to be just a C# error -- and more context is probably needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry wrong tag! but can you help me?

Comment: ret(nolock) means you're calling a function rest with parameter "nolock". You probalby need at least a space, or `from sla.Return ret WITH (nolock)`. But it depends probably on what flavour SQL you are using

Comment: JOIN chains are evaluated from left to right. This means you can't put con.conVCodeInt column in the ON clause before the con table has been joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a keyword, so you need to escape it.

```
 FROM SLA.[Return] ret
```

One might question whether this is a good name for a table, but that is not the direct issue.